# Splitting a line into parts by two different delimiter

Tags: perl

I have lines with the following structure:

```
STRING1 space STRING2 space FREETEXT
```

where both `STRING1` and `STRING2` could be:

1. "space* slash space*" `\s*/\s*` delimited words, e.g. `word1 / word2 / word3`.
2. **or** one signle word. Regex: `\w+`
3. the `FREETEXT` is any string... `(.*)`

I know how to match:

```
* one word such `\w+`
* two delimited words: `\w+\s*/\s*\w+'
```

but don't know how to match "*1 **or** more*" words delimited by `\s*/\s*`, e.g. something like `/(\w+(\s*/\s*)?)/`

maybe more understandable definition:

```
line: string space string space freetext;
string: \w+
        ||
        string \s*/\s* \w+
space: \s+
freetext: .*
```

Need get all 3 parts, e.g. the following code

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
my $slash_string = qr(\w+|\w+\s*/\s*);                     #<- help1 here
while(<DATA>) {
    if( m{^($slash_string)+\s+($slash_string)+\s+(.*)$} ) {  #<- help2 here
        say join ' | ', $1, $2, $3;
    }
}
__DATA__
magnam est dolorem ea est
non / ipsum harum asperiores nesciunt voluptatem
nunt / harum / dicta nisi minus quo similique unde
porro inventore / repudiandae dolorem ipsum
enim  ipsam / aut / numquam illum vero eveniet
natus / voluptas aut / deserunt et nisi sequi est
sed / quam / magni ex / assumenda / et eaque cum et modi
```

should produce the wanted output

```
magnam | est | dolorem ea est
non / ipsum | harum | asperiores nesciunt voluptatem
nunt / harum / dicta | nisi | minus quo similique unde
porro | inventore / repudiandae | dolorem ipsum
enim | ipsam / aut / numquam | illum vero eveniet
natus / voluptas | aut / deserunt | et nisi sequi est
sed / quam / magni | ex / assumenda / et | eaque cum et modi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do as you ask. I've changed `$slash_string` to be a word, followed by zero or more occurrences of a slash followed by another word.

I've also taken the `+` quantifier off your `($slash_string)+` (because we only want one sequence of slash-separated words here) and added the `/x` modifier so that the patterns can be made more readable by adding insignificant whitespace.

I'm pretty sure the output matches your requirement, but I've only checked it by eye.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $slash_string = qr/ \w+ (?: \s* \/ \s* \w+ )* /x;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    if ( / ^ ($slash_string) \s+ ($slash_string) \s+ (.*) /x ) {
        say join '  ', map "[$_]", $1, $2, $3;
    }
}

__DATA__
magnam est dolorem ea est
non / ipsum harum asperiores nesciunt voluptatem
nunt / harum / dicta nisi minus quo similique unde
porro inventore / repudiandae dolorem ipsum
enim ipsam / aut / numquam illum vero eveniet
natus / voluptas aut / deserunt et nisi sequi est
sed / quam / magni ex / assumenda / et eaque cum et modi
```

**output**

```
[magnam]  [est]  [dolorem ea est]
[non / ipsum]  [harum]  [asperiores nesciunt voluptatem]
[nunt / harum / dicta]  [nisi]  [minus quo similique unde]
[porro]  [inventore / repudiandae]  [dolorem ipsum]
[enim]  [ipsam / aut / numquam]  [illum vero eveniet]
[natus / voluptas]  [aut / deserunt]  [et nisi sequi est]
[sed / quam / magni]  [ex / assumenda / et]  [eaque cum et modi]
```

Comment: YES! That's exactly for what I looking. Nicely formatted output. thanx.

Answer (score 3):

If the count of the spaces around the `/` isn't matter, the problem can be reduced to `split at spaces`. The logic:

- replace all `\s*/\s*` with only the `/` - e.g. from the `word1 / word2 / word3` you will get `word1/word2/word3`
- spit the string at the spaces into 3 parts
- replace each `/` back to `/`

code

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s!\s*/\s*!/!g;   #remove all spaces around the /
    my @parts = split /\s+/, $_, 3;
    say join ' | ', map {s!/! / !gr} @parts; #return the spaces
}
```

output

```
magnam | est | dolorem ea est
non / ipsum | harum | asperiores nesciunt voluptatem
nunt / harum / dicta | nisi | minus quo similique unde
porro | inventore / repudiandae | dolorem ipsum
enim | ipsam / aut / numquam | illum vero eveniet
natus / voluptas | aut / deserunt | et nisi sequi est
sed / quam / magni | ex / assumenda / et | eaque cum et modi
```

Comment: Works too, but I more like the regex solution. Thanx.